# Repeated include of utfsym symbols

Tags: symbols

I am using a few symbols from Unicode that the `utfsym` package provides. These symbols are used repeatedly maybe hundreds of times, so I have defined shortcut commands like this to use them:

```latex
\newcommand{\Train}[0]{\xspace}
```

It seems that they are compiled individually each time they are used, which takes a large proportion of the total time of pdf compilation (I am using xelatex). The output log shows the same symbols being compiled repeatedly with lines like this repeating many times.

```
xelatex> (c:/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/utfsym/usym1F688.tikz)
```

Is there any way to "cache" the symbols to use them repeatedly without compiling them repeatedly? All symbols are used only in text mode.

Note: I have tried replacing the literal characters with `\usym{1F688}` etc in the command definition. If anything, this slows it down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experimentation, replacing the `utfsym` use with icons in pdf format that are included with `\includegraphics` seems to be much much faster.